# Detect end of file (cols & rows) in dataframe and delete all extra

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**BACKGROUND:** I have a large excel file converted to .csv. Need to be able to detect the end of the file/dataframe and delete all rows and columns after that. The data has the following format (approx 100 cols and 200 rows):

```
>>>>>Spec. No     Text     .....     LastColumnName     UnnamedN1     UnnammedN2     UnnamedN3     UnnamedN4     .....
0    (some text)  (some text)             0
1    (some text)  (some text)                           2
2    (some text)  (some text)                                          
3
4
5
```

**(1)** The # of columns and the column titles change with every file. However it is certain that the *last column with a name + following 2 columns* are the bounds on the column axis even if they contain no values (in this case UnnamedN4 and N5 would be deleted).

**(2)** Delete all empty rows after the last one with `(some text)` in *Spec No + Text* (in this case rows 3, 4, 5 would be deleted). This will always have some text in the last necessary/relevant row.

**ALREADY TRIED:** Looked at several posts on SO but couldn't find a complete solution for the problem.

**EXPECTED:** New dataframe that looks like -

```
>>>>>Spec. No     Text     .....     LastColumnName     UnnamedN1     UnnammedN2
0    (some text)  (some text)             0
1    (some text)  (some text)                           2
2    (some text)  (some text)
```

Python novice, seeking some help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this for my particular case of data. It is a non-elegant and round-about way of solving but it addresses my problem.

Posting in case the code can help/inspire others for their own projects.

(EoF - End of File)

```
    # Determining the title of the last relevant column from df
    x = df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]
    # Getting the index of the last relevant column
    df.columns.get_loc(x)

    # Deleting all columns after relevant column + 2 (my requirement)
    # Returns dataframe with reduced # of columns
    df1 = df.drop(list(df)[df.columns.get_loc(x)+3 : len(df.columns)], axis=1)

    df_cols = len(df.columns)
    cols_1 = [1]
    cols_2 = [9]
    df_1 = df[df.columns[cols_1]] #dataframe with column 1
    df_2 = df[df.columns[cols_2]] #dataframe with column 9
    df_3 = df_1.join([df_2]) #dataframe with columns 1 and 9
    df_4 = df[df.columns[25:df_cols]] #dataframe with columns 25 (my reqiurement) to EoF 
    df_5 = df_3.join([df_4]) #dataframe with columns 1 and 9 joined to columns 25 to EoF
    df5
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dropna`

```
 df.dropna(how='ALL')
```

Comment: if the case is that the last two cols (UnnamedN1 and Unnamed2) have no values, but I need to keep them as part of the data then does this still work? Is there an option with using indexes of columns etc? (I have updated the Q accordingly)

Comment: how = 'all' means it will delete the row all nan and ur Spec. No     Text   is not nan,so it works

Comment: So this is just for rows? I want the code to check when the row value for specified columns (`Spec no.` and `Text`) is empty and delete all empty rows. _And_ delete all columns after last titled column + next two cols.

Comment: I dont undertand ur rule, if the columns no value,then it should be deleted? which columns do u want to keep

Comment: **(1)** two columns after the last one with a title need to be kept even if they have no data. that is a requirement. **(2)** check through all rows in columns `Spec no.` and `Text` and when they don't have any text, then delete them. Please read the question.